# NeDB didn't update the records

Tags: javascript, node.js, insert-update, nedb

Hi I don't know why this function didn't do anything, even don't show anything on the console, and the callback function didn't work , Sorry if I made an obvious mistake I'm new with node js and NeDb.

here is my update function:

```
var Datastore = require('nedb'),
    db = {
        games: new Datastore({filename: './backend/data/games.db', autoload: true})
    };

var models = { 
     games : {
              update: function (query, update, options, callback) {
                           db.games.update(query, update, options,callback)
             }
            }
           }
module.exports = models;
```

and I called with:

```
var models = require('./models');

models.games.update({_id = game_id}, {$set: {fen: game.fen(), pgn: game.pgn()}}, {}, function(err,numDocs,docs){
      if (err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
         console.log(numDocs);
         console.log(docs);
      }
    });
```

mi database looks like:

```
{"_id":"Egw17uRnAd5sdaKXVlOfxRQ6zr4VnSvFghiXkXHyCi9oiDMqDS","startpos":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1","fen":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1","pgn":"","w_id":"","b_id":""}
{"_id":"6ZlTTQgk2hEhorTGeTV45kkRsUvrxfmROiCJMqLRQoTnvabhqK","startpos":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1","fen":"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1","pgn":"","w_id":"","b_id":""}
```

and the variables for the query

```
game_id = '6ZlTTQgk2hEhorTGeTV45kkRsUvrxfmROiCJMqLRQoTnvabhqK'
game.pgn() = '1. e4 e5 2. Nf3'
game.fen() = 'rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2'
```

**UPDATE 1**

if I put all the code together ,not in separated module, works perfectly

```
var Datastore = require('nedb'),
    db = {
          games: new Datastore({filename: './backend/data/games.db', autoload: true})
          };
db.games.update({_id : game_id}, {$set: {fen: game.fen(), pgn: game.pgn()}}, {}, function(err,numDocs,docs){
   if (err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log(numDocs);
       console.log(docs);
   }
});
```

maybe is something with been working in separated module

**UPDATE 2** for simplicity

The models.js file

```
    var Datastore = require('nedb'),
        db = {
            games: new Datastore({filename: 'database.db', autoload: true})
        };


    var models = {
        games: {
            create: function (id, startpos, fen, pgn, w_id, b_id, callback) {
                db.games.insert({_id: id, startpos: startpos, fen: fen, pgn: pgn, w_id: w_id, b_id: b_id}, callback);
            },
            update: function (query, update, options, callback) {
                db.games.update(query, update, options, callback)
            }
        }
    };

    module.exports = models;
```

the runupdate.js file

```
    var models = require('./models');

    models.games.create('6ZlTTQgk2hEhorTGeTV45kkRsUvrxfmROiCJMqLRQoTnvabhqK', 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1', 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1', '', '', '');

    models.games.update({_id: '6ZlTTQgk2hEhorTGeTV45kkRsUvrxfmROiCJMqLRQoTnvabhqK'}, {$set: {fen: 'r1bqk1nr/pppp1ppp/2n5/2b1p3/2B1P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQ1RK1 b kq - 5 4', pgn: '1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. O-O'}}, {}, function(err,numDocs,docs){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(numDocs);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried to call `db.games.update(query, update, options,callback)` directly instead of `models.games.update`?

Comment: yes and the result is de samme, no update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo while you are calling update method.

`{_id = game_id}` change query with `{_id : game_id}`

***Update :***

Try to change your models.games.update instead of new function and directly assign `db.games.update` like following code block.

```
var models = {
  games : {
     update : db.games.update
  }
}
```

and you might call `models.games.update(/*queries and cb functions*/)`.

Comment: thank, but didnt solve the problem, still not updating the records

Comment: have you debugged your application?  mark a breakpoint on db.games.update and your callbacks, we can sure your db.games.update method works. Because you have no error or any log.

Comment: I update the post, I forgot to say that the database configuration is on separated module maybe this is the reason

Comment: and yes i debug my application and never get into any breakpoint in the callback function

Comment: Was your method called literally when you debugged? Have you pointed update method also ?

Comment: when I call the debug in the first part of my question with breakpoint on the `db.games.update` the brek point stops there but even if i change the callback for a function didn't get into it, same as with breakpoints on `models.games.update` and its callback function. In the **UPDATE 1** part  all works ok

Comment: @efirvida I updated my answer according to your question's updates.

Comment: @efirvida you're welcome, also you might try to return `db.games.update` in a function but this solution is nicer than it in this situation.